# Single API store across 2 different domains?

Tags: database, networking, wso2, wso2-api-manager

So i'm looking into the possibility of having 1 single API store that can showcase APIs across 2 different domains. We are using WSO2 APIM and have all the components up and running on one domain alright. First would this be possible, we know that there is a firewall between the two domains so we would have to open some ACL's to allow this. Also would we be able to share a single Registry DB or would we need to have a Registry DB located in both domains? I'm hoping someone can provide me with a high level architecture view of how this can be achieved.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Matt welcome to SO. Chances of getting answered will be better if the questions are better explained with errors encountered, your analysis etc., Please refer the following link for some tips. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what do you mean by `howcase APIs across 2 different domains`? You mean enabling multiple hostnames for accessing the APIs? Or having a single store for multiple API managers?

Comment: Some of our applications reside in "Domain A" and some in "Domain B". As of now we have all 5 components and DBs hosted on Domain A. But now we need to know how to get the APIs in Domain B into the same store so that all APIs on both domains are located in one store. Or would we need to have a tenant store in Domain B? We are just trying to find out what our options are for hosting one store with APIs from two different domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question looks like we are going to host the APIM Store on one domain and then use a ADFS to allow the users hosted on the other domains AD to gain access to i